# How to create multiple records based on the checked checkbox?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, checkbox, schedule

I'm currently working a program in MS Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition with backend database in MS Access. The program will add a schedule data in MS access once the add button is clicked. The problem is I don't know how to add a record (record with the same data input except from the schedule days field) based on the checked "Days" in the form.

[image: AddScheduleForm]

For example, from the given form above, I want to generate the following output in MS ACCESS 2010 that shows similar records except from the sched_days field.

[image]

As of now I have the following codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class AddSchedForm

    Private Sub AddSchedForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToParent()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If btnAdd.Text = "Add" Then
            Try
                Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;")
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("insert into Schedule (prof_id,course_code,section_code,course_title,units,sched_time1,sched_time2,sched_days,sched_room) values (@profid,@coursecode,@sectioncode,@title,@units,@schedtime1,@schedtime2,@schedday,@schedroom)", conn)

                    With command.Parameters
                        .AddWithValue("@profid", profID.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@coursecode", coursecode.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@sectioncode", sectioncode.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@title", coursetitle.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@units", units.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@schedtime1", time1.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@schedtime2", time2.Text)
                        .AddWithValue("@schedday", "Monday")
                        .AddWithValue("@schedroom", room.Text)
                    End With

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Recorded!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    command.Dispose()
                    conn.Close()
                    Close()
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you!

Comment: you need to add a row for each day.  as the db snap shows, a different day means a whole new row, so set up a loop to INSERT for each checked day.  you may also need to DELETE rows when a class WAS checked for SAT for example and now is not.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But may I know how to create a for loop in visual basic? I'm sorry I'm not that familiar in the syntax used in vb.

Comment: This is something you can research on MSDN: [Vb Loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx), google and tutorial sites.